# How to fetch data from page to angularJS function

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown which displays a city list.

the code is

```
 <input type="text" class=" form-control search_select" placeholder="Departure City" typeahead-on-select="setcodeDepCity(DepartureCity)" ng-model="DepartureCity" typeahead="compx as compx.LocationDescription for compx in CityList | filter:$viewValue" />
```

I have a button, on the click of which I want my selected value to be found.

```
 <a href="" class="btn_search" ng-click="SearchFlight()">SEARCH </a>
```

In the controller, I have written

```
$scope.DepCity ="";
$scope.setcodeDepCity = function (selection) {
    if (selection != null) {
        $scope.DepCity = selection.Code;
        console.log($scope.DepCity);
    }
};
```

But I am unable to extract the selected Item value. 
 `$scope.DepCity` is coming in as `null`.

I have a similar problem with all form fields.

Is there any other method of getting the selected value of the dropdown.

Any help will be welcome

Comment: Remove $scope.DepCity =""; & then check. Or still its coming null, Have a  PLUNKR.

Comment: Sorry rroxysam, it did not work out. I tried your suggestion. but same result.

Comment: Can you send your json data. Because i think, selection is coming right but there is no code property for that selection, That's is why it's give you null.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-typeahead-widget-with-angularjs/

Comment: https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv